# What is this comments structure on javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a project and I see structures like this in a lot parts of the code. My question is what is this and it actually do, since it's wrapped around with the comment marker.

```
/**
 *
 * @param {String} message
 */
```

Comment: [JSDoc](https://devdocs.io/jsdoc/)

Comment: have a look : https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/inline-documentation-standards/javascript/

Comment: this will be treated as comment and while compiling it will be ignored . commenting any thing can be done in two ways single line using // and multiple line /*.....*/ .Comments are basically used to make the code more readable.

Comment: this type of comment is used for specifying the request and response object i.e which type of req you will get for your API and which type of response your api gonna send after processing req object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, this is just a block comment in general.
What confuses you is a convention regarding javascript comments.
Because the language is not typed, there are some comment conventions in place just to unify the way we "talk" about js code in comments.
Nothing magical happens with the line

```
 * @param {String} message
```

All it says to the next developer is that this code has a parameter named message, of type string. Thats it.

Take a look for more info [here](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/inline-documentation-standards/javascript/), it all comes down to "how you should document js code in comments inside the js file", nothing more